# Split a column's values into multiple rows awk/unix/python

Tags: python, unix, awk

Here is a sample row of input data :

```
header: id,indicator,{(pid,days_remaining)}
row:    id_558314,1,{(property_66021,7),(property_24444,1),(property_285395,6)}
```

Expected output of data :

```
header: id,indicator,pid,days_remaining

row1: id_558314,1,property_66021,7
row2: id_558314,1,property_24444,1
row3: id_558314,1,property_285395,6
```

Is this something easily doable using awk/unix/python?

Comment: Why yes, that is not very difficult to do... Now, this forum is not really about us doing your work.

Comment: Did you try anything at all?

Comment: Are you reading the input from a text file?

Comment: I apologize for not posting for what I tried. I am fairly new to stack overflow and awk as well. I was playing around with some sed commands combined with print's: awk -F "{" '{print $2}' | awk -F "(" '{print $2}' | sed 's/),$//g' but I was struggling with running a loop to do this and still print the first and the second columns. @sgp

Comment: @jcoppens I will post all the research I tried moving on. Thanks for the attention and callout.

Comment: @AnandSKumar Yes, I am reading from a text file, however Akshay's approach seems to have solved this for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may help you

```
$ cat file
header: id,indicator,{(pid,days_remaining)}
row:    id_558314,1,{(property_66021,7),(property_24444,1),(property_285395,6)}

$ awk -F, '{gsub(/[{}()]/,"")}FNR==1{print;next}{j=0;p=$1;for(i=3; i<=NF; i+=2){ $1=p;sub(/:/,++j"&",$1);print $1,$2,$i,$(i+1)}}' OFS=,  file
header: id,indicator,pid,days_remaining
row1:    id_558314,1,property_66021,7
row2:    id_558314,1,property_24444,1
row3:    id_558314,1,property_285395,6
```

**Better Readable version**

```
awk -F,  '{
              gsub(/[{}()]/,"")
          }
    FNR==1{
              print
              next
          }
          {
             j=0
             p=$1
             for(i=3; i<=NF; i+=2)
             { 
                $1=p  
                sub(/:/,++j"&",$1)
                print $1,$2,$i,$(i+1) 
             }
          }
        ' OFS=,  file
```

Comment: Hi @AkshayHegde - Thank you so much for the help here. That indeed worked out for me.